# Second Window Creation Objective-C Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I was wondering if it is possible to open a second window with like a button. I have no clue how to do this, please help.

Answer (score 3):

First set up an IBAction to get called when the user clicks the button.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

}
```

In Interface Builder, control-drag from the NSButton object you want to fire that action to the method implementation.

Now, to create a second window, you'll probably want to create a SecondWindowController class to manage it. Declare an IBOutlet to the NSWindow and hook it up in Interface Builder, just like you did for the IBAction (by control-dragging to the IBOutlet declaration).

In the initializer, load the nib file that contains the window you're presenting.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"DubBouncerConversionProgressWindow" owner:self];
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Then, define a method to present the window by calling orderFront: on it.

```
- (void)displayWindow {
    if (![progressWindow isVisible]) {
        [progressWindow setIsVisible:YES];
        [progressWindow orderFront:nil];
    }
 }
```

Now, when the user clicks the button you can call -displayWindow on an instance of SecondViewController.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    [mySecondViewController displayWindow]; 
}
```

Here's a full picture of what's going on:

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : NSObject {
    SecondViewController *mySecondViewController;
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
@implementation FirstViewController

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (!mySecondViewController) {
       // If the second view controller doesn't exist yet, make it!
       mySecondViewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];
    }
    [mySecondViewController displayWindow]; 
}

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : NSObject {
     IBOutlet NSWindow *progressWindow;
}

- (void)displayWindow;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController 

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"DubBouncerConversionProgressWindow" owner:self];
    }
    return self;
 }

 - (void)displayWindow {
    if (![progressWindow isVisible]) {
        [progressWindow setIsVisible:YES];
        [progressWindow orderFront:nil];
    }
 }

 @end
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but you’d be even better off subclass `NSWindowController` and letting in handle the NIB loading and unloading (the latter of which is not handled above).

Comment: @Muttur - There should be a check mark next to this answer. When you click it, it will turn green to indicate you've accepted this response as the answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

Connect the button to the NSWindow's `orderFont:` action. I haven't got Xcode 4, so I can't tell you how to do it in there, but for Xcode 3, open the xib in Interface Builder. While holding the control key, click and drag a line from the button to another window in the nib (drag over the title bar if the window is opened up, otherwise drag it onto the icon in the xib project window). In the menu that pops up, choose "`orderFront:`" or "`makeKeyAndOrderFront:`" (depending on the required behaviour).

If the window is in another nib, you'll need to use an approach like Stephen's.